# Close box click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a code from web. I click on text > opens a box.

I want to close the box when I click outside of box.

This is my javascript code:

```
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub2', 'inline');">
  <span>SHOW BOX</span>
</div>

<div id="sub2">
  <p>This is a test for box.</p>
  <button value='Hide Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub2', 'none');" ;>Click to close box</a>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
 #sub2 { width: 500px; color: black; display: none; background:#eeeeee; display: none; /* Hidden by default */ position: fixed; /* Stay in place */ z-index: 1; overflow: auto; / }
 #sub2 h5 { font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif; font-size:20px; }
```

Comment: where is div closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the onfocusout handler of JavaScript

**Example:**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("BOXID").addEventListener("focusout", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("BOXID").style.visibility='hidden';
}
</script>
```

> NOTE: Replace BOXID with the id of the box u want to close

See also : [Tutorial: onfocusout Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp)